# Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

This code throws error:
**Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference**

```
 function formatDate(dateVal) {

        var date = new Date(parseInt(dateVal.replace('/Date(', '')))
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = date.getDate();
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        return (day.toString().length > 1 ? day : "0" + day) + "/" + (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + year;
    }
```

The value being passed to it is null and is in format like /Date(-62135596800000)/.

Comment: Check if the value is null before replacing

Comment: Check the type of the value being passed and if it's not string, deal with it before trying to call string methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you pass a `null` value, it doesn't have any properties. Make sure you pass the correct value:

```js
function formatDate(dateVal) {
  var date = new Date(parseInt(dateVal.replace('/Date(', '')))
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  return (day.toString().length > 1 ? day : "0" + day) + "/" + (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + year;
}

console.log(formatDate("/Date(-62135596800000)/"));
```

Comment: yeah ok but what if the value from the db is getting passed as null i.e. no value.. to the format function. How to handle that without failing?

Comment: You mean set the `/Date(-62135596800000)/` as a default value @Stacky?

Comment: I mean how to handle the null condition? if value is passing as undefined?

Comment: If it's undefined, use default parameters `function formatDate(dateVal = "/Date(-62135596800000)/") {...}`. If it's null do an internal check with the logical OR operator `dateVal = dateVal || "/Date(-62135596800000)/";`

Comment: @JackBashford—probably needs a bit more work if it's to be a general function, as there may be cases where the value is truthy but not a string. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use default parameters like this **formatDate(dateVal = "" )** ,It allows you to set default values for your function parameters if no value is passed or if undefined is passed:

```
function formatDate(dateVal = "" ) {
  var date = new Date(parseInt(dateVal.replace('/Date(', '')))
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  return (day.toString().length > 1 ? day : "0" + day) + "/" + (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + year;
}
```

Comment: Setting a default value doesn't solve the case where the value being passed is the wrong type. Much better to validate the value if a particular type is required (in this case, string).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that you're expecting a string like "/Date(-62135596800000)/" but are getting something else. So validate the input before calling string methods to parse it, e.g.

```js
function formatDate(dateVal) {

  // Test for string in required format
  if (!/^\/Date\([+-]?\d{1,16}\)\/$/.test(dateVal)) {
    return; // undefined
  }
  
  let date = new Date(parseInt(dateVal.replace('/Date(', '')))
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let day = date.getDate();
  let year = ('000' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-4);
  return (day > 9 ? day : "0" + day) + "/" +
         (month > 9 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" +
          year;
}

// Simple tests
['/Date(-62135596800000)/',
  null,
  NaN,
  'sweet',
  1561853541934,
  '/Date(1561853541934)/'].forEach(
    v => console.log(v + ': ' + formatDate(v))
);
```

Then in the caller, you can test if you got back a string (success) or *undefined*, which indicates invalid input that you'll need to deal with.